# Customize colors in "git gui"?

Tags: git

`git gui` is a pretty useful graphical client, but it's utility is somewhat by the coloring of the diff: Context text is typeset in black (hence overly emphasized), while changes are highlighted in weak shades of red and green – a problem with partial red-green color blindness.

For `git diff` the colors can be configured (settings `color.diff.*`), but `git gui` ingores those settings.

Are there any settings available, that affect the color choices in `git gui`?

Comment: I believe you can use a custom diff utility too, btw.

Comment: @Dai Would that custom diff utility still be integrated with the `git gui` though, or open as separate window? Since it doesn't respect `color.diff` settings, I assumed that `git gui` does the coloration itself, and thus would ignore anything produced by alternative diff tools, unless the diff-tool is external (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12169973/invoking-external-difftool-from-git-gui). That would however sacrifice half the convenience of "all in one place".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With Git 2.30 (Q1 2021),

See [commit 4d22c05](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4d22c0505f85b83f73c580049c74c5a7c7e0a5d4) (22 Nov 2020) by [Serg Tereshchenko (`last-partizan`)](https://github.com/last-partizan).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit f4d8e19](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f4d8e191230b3d233005720085092b97e9bf32f1), 18 Dec 2020)</sup>

> ### [`git-gui`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4d22c0505f85b83f73c580049c74c5a7c7e0a5d4): Fix selected text colors
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Serg Tereshchenko</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Pratyush Yadav</sup>

> Added selected state colors for text widget.
>
> Same colors for active and inactive selection, to match previous behaviour.

This suggests you can edit the Tcl sources of git-gui to change any color you need.
This was for instance suggested in "[Dark theme for git gui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61115428/6309)"

Example of color customization:

With Git 2.30 (Q1 2021),

See [commit da4d86d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/da4d86da97a316413cf25bef99332525dbfb4d59) (18 Dec 2020), and [commit f9481b1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f9481b195b867dbdeead70d988e2e00d438d6f52) (22 Nov 2020) by [Stefan Haller (`stefanhaller`)](https://github.com/stefanhaller).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit f4d8e19](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f4d8e191230b3d233005720085092b97e9bf32f1), 18 Dec 2020)</sup>

> ### [`git-gui`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/da4d86da97a316413cf25bef99332525dbfb4d59): use gray background for inactive text widgets
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Stefan Haller</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Pratyush Yadav</sup>

> This makes it easier to see at a glance which of the four main views has the keyboard focus.